# "Observe" vs. "Observate"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I know I'm splitting hairs over here but can someone confirm with me the difference between "Observe" and "Observate".

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/observate

I feel there is a very fine difference between the two words. The first one "Observe" feels more general, looking at a whole scene with many elements, whereas "Observate" has a slight scientific tone and focus on looking at only one particular element (i.e. ignoring irrelevant stuff in the scene background).

I ran a google search before posting this and saw many sources using the word “observate” including an entry in the online Oxford dictionary. I also vaguely remember this word from chemistry class at school. Hence my confusion.

Comment: I'm positive I've never ever heard 'observate' before in any context.

Comment: "Observate" seems very obscure, but is in use. I did a couple of Google searches, for 'mouse DNA "observate"' and 'mouse DNA "observe" (to deliberately target scientific articles)'. Judging by the number of hits "Observate" has about 0.04% the usage of "Observe".

Comment: ...sounds a little like [conversate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-conversate-a-real-word)

Comment: @Cascabel thanks for the useful comment :) so far that's the best reasoning

Comment: I've found a 16th c. adjectival attestation of  **observate** (i.e. "seen") in a Scots translation of Livy by John Bellenden, Archdean of Moray and Canon of Ross, published in Edinburgh in 1872. *Thus was nocht the maner observate be the remanent kingis...*

Comment: I first came across the word observate while learning to ride a motorbike. On stopping at any busy junction, my instructor (clad head to toe in black leather and very scary - he once threatened to break my fingers if I ever dumped the clutched again) would shout, 'observate!' I was too afraid to tell him that it wasn't a real word. But on reflection I can see the need for it. More than 'observe' or 'look' or similar words it captures what I needed to do - observe everything going on, all around, in a very active way. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Observate" is not a real word. "Observe"(v.), "observation"(n.), and "observant"(adj.) are words, but "observate" (and its commonly used brother "observating") is not a word. Many people use these two terms, but they're not in any* dictionary (that I could find) other than Urban Dictionary.

Source: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/observating.1175407/

Edit: *Apparently "observate" is found in exactly one dictionary.
Edit 2: [This](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/english/?q=observate) is all I got from the Cambridge dictionary online; where did you find an entry?

Comment: It is in [the dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/observate) and its in use if you search, so I think that makes it a "real word".

Comment: @James I mean I guess... but [the actual Oxford English Dictionary site](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/129881?rskey=fkfeeZ&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) names the word as a malapropism.

Comment: @gymnast66x - I think yours is an important point to make, b/c it seems like a case where citing a single dictionary as an arbiter of the English language might be inappropriate. Maybe instead of saying it's not a real word, you could say what dictionaries it's not in. FWIW, I'm a scientist, and I've never used or read the word observate that I am aware, possibly with the exception of articles in low-impact journals (i.e. that are not thoroughly copyedited) scientists whose native tongue is not (or likely not) English.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Oxford dictionary and not Cambridge https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/observate

Comment: Also my go-to German-English dictionary had the entry for Observate https://www.dict.cc/english-german/observate.html

Comment: It's not a word in use in Modern English. It's a back-formation from the noun _observation_, a borrowing from Latin. The Modern English word is _observe_. Nobody ever says it, and only those looking for it ever find it. Forget about it.